# Im using html code and css in c# to design the button and i don't know how to redirect it to another page after clicked it(ASP.net)

Tags: c#, html

I try using href and posbackturl but it doesn't work . I started learning c# since last week so im still weak on it .Can anyone teach me how to solve it ?

```
<button class="button" style="vertical-align:middle"><span>Add Contact </span></button>
```

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET page (ASPX) or plain HTML? Please provide clearer details about current problem.

Comment: Sir, im using ASP.net page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an HTML button that acts like a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to simply redirect to to the page, then simply you can forward it by just providing the page to href.

```
<a href="addcontact.aspx" style="vertical-align:middle" role="button">Add Contact</a>
```

If you simply want to redirect you can use LinkButton.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/addcontact.aspx">Add Contact</asp:LinkButton>
```

And if you want to perform some functionality on server side, then you may have to use OnClick event to bind with button which will look like this. 
Web Form

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">Add Contact</asp:LinkButton>
```

C# Server Side

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Functionaltiy
   Response.Redirect("/addcontact.aspx");
}
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: I’m happy to help, happy coding.